# n-th roots of unity (some equivalences)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $q$ be a prime power and $n$ a positive integer s.t. $\gcd(n, q) = 1$.
Let $E(n)$ be the set of the complex $n$-th roots of unity. For every positive integer $d$ such that $d | n$ , let

$$Q_d(x) := \prod_{\alpha \in E(n):\mathrm{ord}(\alpha)=d} (x- \alpha)$$

Now I've got a (maybe simple and easy...) question: if $p$ is prime and $m$ a positive integer coprime to $p$. In that case, why is it true that $Q_p(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{p-1}$ ?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: [Cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)?